# Does branch support the android built in browser?

Tags: branch.io

I'm implementing a custom deepview using branch's web sdk. Essentially I have a page with a button on it. In brief:

```
    (function(b,r,a,n,c,h,_,s,d,k)...
    branch.init('key_test...
    branch.deepview(
        {
          'channel': 'landing_page',
          'feature': 'launcher',
          data : {
            custom: 'data',
            '$desktop_url': 'https://x.com',
            '$fire_url': 'https://x.com',
            '$blackberry_url': 'https://x.com',
            '$windows_phone_url': 'https://x.com'
          }
        },
        {
          'open_app': false
        },
        function(err) {
            console.log(err || 'no error');
        }
    );
    ...
    <button onclick="branch.deepviewCta()">Native App</a>
```

...

When I navigate to this page in the android built-in browser and then click the button (I've tried android 6.0 and 4.4.2) I see the following:

[image: Android 6 built in browser]

Because I haven't installed the app I would expect to be taken to the app store which is what does happen on ios and when using chrome or firefox on android (on the same devices).

What is the expected behaviour for the android built-in browser when I click my button? Is there anything I may not have configured correctly? In the branch dashboard under link settings for android I have selected:
- "I have an android app"
- Android URI Scheme: 'myapp://'
- Google play search -> myapp
- Enable app links + sha256

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you are getting the ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME could be because of the following reasons:

1) The user is being blocked by a sign-in firewall router feature
2) The user is opening a Branch deep link within an in-app browser that is not compatible with deep linking

Make sure that neither of the above is true, in case of your testing.

You can check the deep linking from a deepviewcta() works for the Facebook webview. If you paste the link to your webpage on Facebook, clicking on the Deepview CTA ('Native App' in case of your webpage) should redirect to the Play Store page for your App if App is not installed.